# Spark: decimalType not found

Tags: scala, apache-spark, decimal, user-defined-functions, bigdecimal

I am trying to use DecimalType(18,2). The following is my codes:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes._

object ETL {
  //created a DecimalType
  val decimalType = DataTypes.createDecimalType(18,2)

  case class SKU(price_usd: decimalType)
)
```

I got error `decimalType not found`. How to fix it? Thanks

BTW, I tried `BigDecimal`, which is of (38, 18). but I need (18, 2). In my spark job, I used sql to get some columns which are of (18, 2). And I would like to write UDF to process them. I have no idea how to define the date types of decimal in UDF.

Comment: "D" should be uppercase in  price_usd  :  DecimalType

Comment: @C.S.ReddyGadipally At beginning, I used `DecimalType`. still got the same error

Answer (score 1):

In you code decimalType is actually not a scala type identifier - it is a value of class DecimalType. So, you can't use it where compiler expects a type identifier.

In order to write UDF you may just use java.math.BigDecimal as an argument type. No need to specify precision and scale. Though, if you really need these values to be set for computations inside the UDF you may try to specify them in MathContext.

```
package HelloSpec.parser

import com.holdenkarau.spark.testing.{DataFrameSuiteBase, SharedSparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{DecimalType, StructField, StructType}
import org.scalatest.FlatSpec


case class SKU(price_usd: BigDecimal)

object Fields {
  val PRICE_USD = "price_usd"
}

class TestSo extends FlatSpec with DataFrameSuiteBase with SharedSparkContext {

  import Fields._

  it should "not fail" in {
    import spark.implicits._
    val df = Seq(
      SKU(BigDecimal("1.12")),
      SKU(BigDecimal("1234567890123456.12")),
      SKU(BigDecimal("1234567890123456.123")),
      SKU(BigDecimal("12345678901234567.12"))
    ).toDF

    df.printSchema()
    df.show(truncate = false)

    assert(
      df.schema ==
        StructType(Seq(StructField(name = PRICE_USD, dataType = DecimalType(38, 18))))
    )

    val castedTo18_2 = df.withColumn(PRICE_USD, df(PRICE_USD).cast(DecimalType(18, 2)))
    castedTo18_2.printSchema()
    castedTo18_2.show(truncate = false)
    assert(
      castedTo18_2.schema ==
        StructType(Seq(StructField(name = PRICE_USD, dataType = DecimalType(18, 2))))
    )
    assert {
      castedTo18_2.as[Option[BigDecimal]].collect.toSeq.sorted == Seq(
        // this was 12345678901234567.12 before the cast,
        // but the number with 17 digits before the decimal point exceeded the 18-2=16 allowed digits
        None,
        Some(BigDecimal("1.12")),
        Some(BigDecimal("1234567890123456.12")),
        // note, that 1234567890123456.123 was rounded to 1234567890123456.12
        Some(BigDecimal("1234567890123456.12"))
      )
    }

    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{udf, col}
    val processBigDecimal = udf(
      // The argument type has to be java.math.BigDecimal, not scala.math.BigDecimal, which is imported by default
      (bd: java.math.BigDecimal) => {
        if (bd == null) {
          null
        } else {
          s"${bd.getClass} with precision ${bd.precision}, scale ${bd.scale} and value $bd"
        }
      }
    )

    val withUdfApplied = castedTo18_2.
      withColumn("udf_result", processBigDecimal(col(PRICE_USD)))

    withUdfApplied.printSchema()
    withUdfApplied.show(truncate = false)

    assert(
      withUdfApplied.as[(Option[BigDecimal], String)].collect.toSeq.sorted == Seq(
        None -> null,
        Some(BigDecimal("1.12")) -> "class java.math.BigDecimal with precision 19, scale 18 and value 1.120000000000000000",
        Some(BigDecimal("1234567890123456.12")) -> "class java.math.BigDecimal with precision 34, scale 18 and value 1234567890123456.120000000000000000",
        Some(BigDecimal("1234567890123456.12")) -> "class java.math.BigDecimal with precision 34, scale 18 and value 1234567890123456.120000000000000000"
      )
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried `BigDecimal`, which is of (38, 18). but I need (18, 2)

Comment: What is the use case? Why casting the column in DataFrame to (18, 2) does not work for you?

Comment: In my spark job, I used sql to get some columns which are of (18, 2). And I would like to write UDF to process them. I have no idea how to define the date types of decimal in UDF.

Comment: This makes it a different question =). I've added example of UDF.